# Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Tags: properties, undefined

When the function call below gets run it returns this error.
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of 
 undefined" I am trying to change the background color of a class called 
 .jumbotron. I have tried everything I can thing of so far.

```
Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

clrElementJumbo("cornsilk");

function clrElementJumbo(scolor) {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron");
  el.style.backgroundColor = scolor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the code

```
       var el = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron");
```

with the following

```
       var el=document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron")[0];
```