# TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting an odd error when trying to edit the status DIV.

The styleBox() function should edit the status DIV by changing the colour and backgroundColor. However every time I run the function I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
```

It does not make sense to me because when I see if I'm selecting the div correctly, I don't get an undefined error:

```
document.getElementById('status');
>> <div id=​"status" style>​</div>​
```

I think it has something to do with the "style" in the status DIV but 'm not sure how to proceed. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244757/cannot-read-property-backgroundcolor-of-undefined) but that has to do with selecting classes not IDs.

My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Day 11 - Functions Visuals
        </title>

        <style>
            #box {
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                background-color:black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="group">
            <button id="blue">Blue</button>
            <button id="red">Red</button>
            <button id="green">Green</button>
            <div id="status" style=""></div> << -- This is what is tripping me up
        </div>

        <div id="box"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">



            // Create variables for each id

            blueButton = document.getElementById('blue');
            redButton = document.getElementById('red');
            greenButton = document.getElementById('green');
            status = document.getElementById('status');
            box = document.getElementById('box');

            function styleBox() {

                box.style.width = "50px";
                box.style.height = "50px";
                status.innerHTML = "The box is changed";
                status.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
                status.style.color = "#FFF";
            };


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a global var called status *may* be conflicting with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX you're correct. I did not know about the reserved name list https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,

Javascript has reserved words which cannot be used these reserved words as variables, labels, or function names.

One of those words is "status" which I named one of my variables. After changing the variable name my code worked.

For a list of reserved words, check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) list.

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words) is the definitive guide and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a very useful resource. Note that *status* is not a reserved word, it's a property of the (browser) *window* object that is implementation dependent. If you incorrectly use a reserved word, most environments will tell you with an error message.

Comment: Will refer here next time. Thanks!